# Find and classify the singularities in $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$ of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(e^{\frac{1}{z}}+4)^2-9}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find and classify the singularities in $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$ of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(e^{\frac{1}{z}}+4)^2-9}$$

So first of all, I look for the $z\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $(e^{\frac{1}{z}}+4)^2-9=0$ which is whenever $e^{1/z}=-7$ or $e^{1/z}=-1$. So my first question is: Here I should choose a branch of logarithm to calculate for which $z\in \Bbb{C}$ the latter are true? If that's the case, for each branch I will have a different singularity?

And a problem that I always have, $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity in $z=0$, this implies $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$? If not, what would be the strategy to study what happens at $z=0$?

Comment: What is the relation between the zeroes and the poles of $f$ and $1/f$?

Comment: The order of a pole of $f$ is the same as the multiplicity of a $0$ of $1/f$. But I don't see how that may answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's take $e^{1/z}=-7$ as an example. Let $w=1/z$; certainly solving $e^w=-7$ is easy enough: $w=\ln(7)+(2k+1)\pi i, \, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, all we do is go back to $z=1/w$.

$$z=\frac{\overline{w}}{{|w|}^2}=\frac{\ln(7)-(2k+1)\pi i}{{\ln(7)}^2+{(2k+1)}^2{\pi}^2}, \, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Of course, the situation with $e^{1/z}=-1$ is similar and yields

$$z=-\frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}\,i, \, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

So, we now know all the poles of $f$ without having to resort to logarithm branches.

Regarding the singularity at $z=0$, one way to characterize singularities is as follows:

- Removable singularities remain bounded near the point;
- The absolute value near poles goes to infinity;
- Near an essential singularity, nearly all possible values are assumed.

Can you see how using this characterization solves our problem?

Comment: The first part, excellent. Regarding $z=0$: I know that $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity in $z=0$. Now I think $\frac{1}{e^{1/z}}$ should therefore also have an essential singularity in $z=0$. However I am not being able to see if all possible values are assumed..

Comment: If $f$ assumes (nearly) all possible values, what can you say of the values assumed by $1/f$?